# Getting method params

Tags: php

Lets say I have a class like:

```
class SomeClass{
    function someAction($param1,$param2){}
}
```

Is there any way to get analyzing data like `array('param1','param2')` *without* actual execution of method? Preferably without php extensions or prior code analysis (fopen...)

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great, thank you all, solved it with something like

```
$oRuleContainer = new cRuleContainer();
$rContainer = new ReflectionClass('cRuleContainer');

$rMethod = $rContainer->getMethod($aRule['method']);
$aArgs = $rMethod->getParameters();

if($aArgs){
    foreach($aArgs as $refArgument){
        $arrPassedArgData[$refArgument->name]=$_POST[$refArgument->name];
    }
}

if(call_user_func_array(array($oRuleContainer,$aRule['method']),$arrPassedArgData)){
//success
}
```

More details at
http://kurapov.name/rus/technology/web/php/reflection_php_brms/

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the [Reflection class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to get info about method(s) and params.